# User profile is not including all Organization Unit

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-services, user-profile-service, active-directory, user-profile-property

I'm trying to contact `/_vti_bin/People.asmx` service from a simple javascript call.

This web service is returning some user informations. For example I receive these informations in the `SPS-DistinguishedName` field:

```
CN=FirstName LastName,OU=IT,OU=Accounts,DC=DomainName,DC=local
```

These informations are correct, but it seems missing the first level of OU (Organization Unit) where this user is part of.

And this is my current scenario:

```
DOMAIN
-- OU1**
---- ACCOUNTS
------ IT
-- OU2**
---- ACCOUNTS
------ IT
```

OU with ** are missing from `SPS-DistinguishedName`.

It is something that I have to correct in the User Profile sync service?

Should I force a re-sync?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the old ASMX service. On SharePoint 2016 you should be able to use the Search REST API and specify the People Result Source for your SourceID. I haven't looked in a while but the OU would depend on how you have configured the import. Is there another attribute you can use to accomplish the same end goal, like Department?